# How to log in a different file each message using python logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a system monitoring a directory and pumping each log file going to that directory and deleting the file after.

My goal is to print each log to a different file.

I would like to do `log.info("my log")` and it would create a file name `1555360447.log` where `1555360447` is a timestamp.

That file can then be pumped.

I'm struggling with the file handlers...

I tried `TimeRotatingFileHandler` but it creates the file too early and the empty file is getting pumped.

I want something that is the equivalent of:

```
with open(f'{time.time()'}.log', 'w') as the_file:
    the_file.write('my log')
```

But using the python logging module.